# Need A Script In Generating Link Urls

Tags: php, youtube

I need a script which automatically generates links to clickable buttons on highlight links with text.

For eg. What I want is that my links which look like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaM3T9IZPm0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSMbt6Uz0iA
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zcBXcA1S7U
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YInymLn-VS0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9EhBSDnJmVw
```

are should be converted and changed like these,

```
Youtube Video 1
Youtube Video 2
Youtube Video 3
Youtube Video 4
Youtube Video 5
```

These are HTML anchor texts so when I click Youtube Video 1 link the first Youtube video link should be opened.

I want to to do it in bulk like 50-100 links so is there a short way or a script or PHP code which I could use .

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

I have found this script and it is working but there is one problem which needs to be resolved.

```
<?php

    echo '<h3>Drop some urls in the box, then click the button<br />
    <FORM name="urlbox" action="" method="POST">
    <textarea style="background:#eee;" rows="20" cols="30" name="rawurls"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Make Links" name="submit">

    </FORM>
    ';

    $rawurls=$_POST["rawurls"];

    $explodedurls=explode("\n",$_POST["rawurls"]);
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach ($explodedurls as $eachurl) {

                    echo '<a href="'.$eachurl.'">'.$eachurl.$i'</a>';

            }
    echo '</pre>';

?>
```

The problem is that I want the output to be like I have shown above

Youtube Video 1 
Youtube Video 2

and so on.

Comment: Your question got killed with `Need A Script...` not good. Had you Google'd some code and shown us what you tried and had problems with, we might've been able to help.

Comment: Sorry but I was just trying to find a way because I do not know how to start so I wrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this....

```
<?php
$yourlinkarray=['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaM3T9IZPm0','http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSMbt6Uz0iA'];
$i=1;
foreach($yourlinkarray as $links)
{
    echo "<a href=$links>Youtube Video $i</a><br>";
    $i++;
}
```

---

**EDIT :**

```
$i=1;
foreach ($explodedurls as $eachurl) {
        echo "<a href=$eachurl>Youtube Video $i</a>";
                    $i++;
            }
```

Comment: What about the links input. Secondly, what if I want it to generate an html file with links alligned?

Comment: You need to pass the video links inside your `$yourlinkarray` as shown.

Comment: Shankar, your script is working. I have editted the post above with another script but the problem is that the output is inform of urls. Can you help me name them please. Thanks

Comment: You may want to add a `\n` in `echo "<a href=$eachurl>Youtube Video $i</a>";` such as `echo "<a href=$eachurl>Youtube Video $i</a>" . "\n";` that will put a space between all links. @user2354128 or `echo "<a href=$eachurl>Youtube Video $i</a>" . " ";`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaM3T9IZPm0" alt="Youtube Video 1">Youtube Video 1</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for help but I need a script for it but not anchor text url. Anyway, thanks.